# Debugging Issue on browser for Sales force Hybrid App

Tags: android, ios, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am trying to develop a sales force hybrid app which should work for ios , android. 
Currently I am facing the issue to debug the code in browser, that means i am not able run my app on browser it just redirects to login page for sales force and fails. 
To debug i have to always run the app in simulator and debug it which is a headache. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

To debug your app in browsers you can use [Fire Bug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

My issue is i cant get past oAuth screen right after login.

here is what exactly happens:

When used force-server or any other server, first time app gets a pop up for salesforce login. after that salesforce want user to "allow" that app to access data.

**ALL DONE as per salesforce requirement** but it wont move past that.

for Mozilla browser error is browser doesn't understand url and for chrome Cache error.